# Sencha touch: How to refresh input label

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, extjs

I have an `Ext.form.Select` that I want to update it's label dynamically when it's value changes. Simple as it sounds, it refuses to work:

```
var musicInCarInput = new Ext.form.Select({
    options: [
        {text: "Yes", value: "yes"},
        {text: "Maybe", value: "maybe"},
        {text: "No", value: "no"}
    ],
    name: "music",
    value: "maybe",
    label: '<img src="/static/images/comfort_icons/music_maybe_small.png" />',
    listeners: {
        change: function()
        {
            musicInCarInput.label = '<img src="/static/images/comfort_icons/music_'+musicInCarInput.getValue()+'_small.png" />';
        }
    }
});
```

I tried to call `doLayout()` after I change the label, but I'm told that the input has no property 'doLayout', although documented so.

Any ideas anyone ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer came to me from [realjax](http://www.sencha.com/forum/member.php?85197-realjax) on SenchaTouch forums: there is a property on the select (that I'm ashamed that I've missed) called labelEl, which can be used to update the bale like this:

```
musicInCarInput.labelEl.setHTML([your hmtl stuff])
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer the answer directly, because I didn't found how to update the label, so further answers are welcomed. The solution that i found for me is to get the label image by and id, and update it.

If someone else needs this, here is the code:

```
var musicInCarInput = new Ext.form.Select({
    options: [
        {text: "Yes", value: "yes"},
        {text: "Maybe", value: "maybe"},
        {text: "No", value: "no"}
    ],
    name: "music",
    value: "maybe",
    label: '<img id="music_input_label" src="/static/images/comfort_icons/music_maybe_small.png" />',
    listeners: {
        change: function()
        {
            el = Ext.getDom('music_input_label');
            el.setAttribute("src", '/static/images/comfort_icons/music_'+this.getValue()+'_small.png')
        }
    }
});
```